# Deserialising large data taking too long

Tags: c#

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Facility> AllFacilities()
{
    string jsondata  = Data.GetFacilities;
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerialize();
    javaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = int32.MaxValue;
    return javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<Facility>>(jsondata);
}
```

The deserialization is taking way too long when there is large amount of data. Is there a way to improve its performance. Like to return a part of data and show that to the user while loading the rest. My application just displays the xml formatted output in the browser page

I tried the yield return. I don't know much about it. What I was expecting was   each facility record in the 'jsondata' is deserialised and returned, one by one so that user can see something while the others are getting loaded.  But that is not happening .

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Facility> AllFacilities()
{
    string jsondata  = Data.GetFacilities;
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    javaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    foreach (var x in javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<Facility>(jsondata))
    {
        yield return x;
    }
}
```

Both theses snippets return the data the same way. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do it? Please give me suggestions.

Comment: Try using JSON.NET, it seems to be more efficient than the built in serializer.

Comment: the line ```foreach (var x in javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<Facility>>(json))``` is still executing the deserialization over the entire JSON object at once, then iterating over each resulting record, which is why that didn't help

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried JSON.NET but it didn't help with the performance much only by few seconds. This deserialisation is taking minutes to load the data. How can I chunk the jsondata before deserialization? What is the best way to do it? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721776/3896566) and see if that works. I've never used it, so I'm only posting a comment instead of an answer, but it looks like you can trigger a callback as it parses each entry. Total processing time might not be different, but you would be able to get data and start using it as it runs through the json string

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try that out and let you know.

Comment: How large is the json file?

Comment: The json string  has 6757067 records each with depth 12.

Comment: The stackoverflow solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721776/3896566 seems close to solution but instead writing to console how can I return the data from the controller so that it displays the data in browser. I was able to display record fields (t=> t.text) in console window one by one using this. But the data was not displayed in xml format. I need the records xml formatted too

Answer (score 0):

Try to use paging (JArray class from JSON.NET) -

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Facility> Facilities(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    string jsondata = Data.GetFacilities;
    JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsondata);
    return a.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize).Select(x => x.ToObject<Facility>());
}
```

Comment: but.. this is the exact code that OP already has. How is that "more straightforward"?

Comment: This is the code I was looking for suggestions for improvement since the deserialization of large jsondata is taking too long.

Comment: My suggestion then would be to either [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44832982/edit) your answer so that it actually answers the question or delete it. In its current state it's not answering anything

Comment: My page that displays the xml formatted data doesn't actually need a pager (where you can click and move from one page to next). It just shows xml formatted data.  Is there a way to do this without actually having a pager ?

Comment: What do you mean "Like to return a part of data and show that to the user while loading the rest."?

Comment: The xml page that is displayed has a number of <Facility> records. Say like 10,000 records. Since it takes a long time to display this data, I want it to display grab some records deserialise it and then to show to the user while it is working on loading the rest of the data (instead of deserializing the whole data and then displaying to the user).